# Animate image left to right on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to do is I have around 6 inline images I want slide them left to right on specific position and stop there for each image. And images have to slide at the time the scrool comes over them.
I tried this javascript for it (totally new to JS)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($this.scrollTop()>300)
{
    $('.onfoot1').slideright();
}
function slideright(){
    var a = getElementsByClassName('.onfoot1');
    var stoppos = 100;
    if (parseInt(a.style.left)< stoppos )
    {
        a.style.left = parseInt(a.style.left) + 3 + "px";
        setTimeout(slideright , 1);
    }
 }
});
```

Markup

```
<div class="onfoot1"></div>
```

CSS

```
div.onfoot1{
  content:url(../img/onfoot1.jpg);
  left:0;    
}
```

Comment: Use the ScrollMagic library with GSAP. (Manually using scroll events can have bad performance if you're not careful.) And btw, don't animate `left`, use `transform: translate` because it avoids layout recalculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've put together a working examle for your code: https://jsfiddle.net/hmzw9y65/

I've made a few assumptions there... You are using `$(...)` syntax so I guessed you are using JQuery. JQuery has a .animate() function which should do the trick (http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Also I guessed that you may want to make the css-position of the div fixed so it stays on screen when you scroll.

EDIT: I noticed that you don't want you image on the bottom of the screen but animating when screen reaches it. Updated my fiddle to do that: https://jsfiddle.net/hmzw9y65/1/

Comment: can you post code for image comming from ritght please

Comment: I guess you still want your content being left sided so I tweaked the solution with using a hidden overflow on the parent container and positioning the images originally at `left:100%`: https://jsfiddle.net/hmzw9y65/2/

Comment: thankyou buddy there is one issue with it.... when i try to run it with mozilla content does not show on screen.

Comment: the reason for this is that mozilla does not accept content values on normal css selectors. they require them to be inside a `:after` selector: https://jsfiddle.net/hmzw9y65/3/

Comment: Thanks for your help rene. :)